# Session variable only changing occasionally in php

Tags: php

I have a calendar that retrieves table data from a database and inputs the events into the calendar. I store one of the columns into a session variable to access on another page (a longer description of the event that the user can click on). My issue is the session variable isnt changing in each iteration of the loop. Every event in the same month links to the same session variable, but if I change the month, the first event is right and the rest all have it's data. Why is this session variable only changing one time per month? Thanks for any help! I do have `session_start()` on both pages.

```
/* print "blank" days until the first of the current week */
    for($x = 0; $x < $running_day; $x++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>';
        $days_in_this_week++;
    endfor;

    /* keep going with days.... */
    for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
        $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day"><div style="position:relative;height:100px;">';
            /* add in the day number */
            $calendar.= '<div class="day-number">'.$list_day.'</div>';
            $event_day = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$list_day;
            if(isset($events[$event_day])) {
                foreach($events[$event_day] as $event) {
                    $_SESSION['desc'] = $event['longDesc']; //this is the line I am referencing
                    $calendar.= '<div class="event">'.$event['title'].'<br>'.$event['time'].'<br>'.$event['shortDesc'].'<br><a href="https://cts.gruv.org/short/cal/description.php">More</a></div>';
                }
            }
            else {
                $calendar.= str_repeat('<p>&nbsp;</p>',2);
            }
        $calendar.= '</div></td>';
        if($running_day == 6):
            $calendar.= '</tr>';
            if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
                $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
            endif;
            $running_day = -1;
            $days_in_this_week = 0;
        endif;
        $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
    endfor;

    /* finish the rest of the days in the week */
    if($days_in_this_week < 8):
        for($x = 1; $x <= (8 - $days_in_this_week); $x++):
            $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day-np">&nbsp;</td>';
        endfor;
    endif;
```

description.php page

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

include  ('../dbinfo.php');
session_start();

$db=mysqli_connect($dbhostname,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname[0]);

$description =  $_SESSION['desc'];

print($description);

session_unset();

mysqli_close($db);//Close the DB Connection

?>
```

Comment: @John Conde I do have session_start()... obviously if the session is working for each month...re-open?

Comment: Have you tried setting it to a normal variable eg `$description`? To see what it behaves like...

Comment: @JeroenBellemans I'm assuming you mean in the foreach loop where I am currently assigning it to a session? If I did that how would I ever access it on the description page?

Comment: @RyanVincent but wont I get a fatal error trying to put a string into that? `$event['longDesc']` holds a string with a description.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have `session_start();` on both pages but you also have to call session_start *before* ANY body output is sent to the client. Have you tried placing `session_start();` at the *very* top of your page? Perhaps `include  ('../dbinfo.php');` is spitting out an error or whitespace or some other kind of output.

edit: also why are you calling `session_unset`? This clears the `$_SESSION` variable. It's like assigning `$_SESSION = array();` are you sure you want to do that? Whatever you assigned to your session will be cleared when you go to another page.

Comment: `session_start()` is the first thing I have on both pages. The unset was more just testing to try to figure out a way to get the session to clear itself each time the loop is run. Right now it is only resetting when I go to a new month. https://cts.gruv.org/short/cal/query.php if you would like to see what I mean. For November, all the "more" links share the same session variable, but if you go the next month, it changes but does the same thing if I populate the calendar with more events in the same month. @Macmee